# Double polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

In my rails app I have two models:
`Person` and `Company`. I need to specify many-to-many relationship between any pairs of this objects. So I should be able do like this:

```
@connections = @person.connections
```

where `@connections` is an array of `Person` and `Company` objects.

Right now I've created `ConnectionBinding` model for this and it does not work as wanted:

```
class ConnectionBinding < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :connect_from, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :connect_to,   polymorphic: true
end
```

It thougths `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicSourceError` exception

Does anybody already solve this problem? Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I'm wondering if STI can help in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanx Chris for showing the idea. But I need to do some changes to make this work.
The problem of Chris example is that if I call `person_connections` method it will generate wrong query.

```
Person.find(720).person_connections
```

generates this SQL

```
SELECT  "people".* FROM "people"
INNER JOIN "connection_bindings"
  ON "people"."id" = "connection_bindings"."connect_to_id"
WHERE "connection_bindings"."person_id" = 720
  AND "connection_bindings"."connect_to_type" = 'Person'
```

That `person_id` column should be `connect_from_id`. So I need to add `:as => :connect_from` option to `has_many :connection_bindings` to show ActiveRecord that its a polymorphic association.

```
has_many :connection_bindings, :as => :connect_from
has_many :person_connections,  :through => :connection_bindings,
  :source => :connect_to, source_type: 'Person'
has_many :company_connections, :through => :connection_bindings,
  :source => :connect_to, source_type: 'Company'
```

But it is still not enough. I need to be able to get reverse connections. So if Person `@a` adds connection to Person `@b`? method connections should show that connection in both directions `@a.connections` and `@b.connections`.

And now I think I can do this by adding couple of additional associations and aggregation methods.

Answer (score 7):

You need to tell ActiveRecord the associated column that it is looking for. I'm guessing you want to have the following:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connection_bindings
  has_many :companies, :through => :connection_bindings
  has_many :people, :through => :connection_bindings
end

class company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connection_bindings
  has_many :companies, :through => :connection_bindings
  has_many :people, :through => :connection_bindings
end
```

The problem there is that you have two tables putting there id in one column and Rails doesn't know which table to look up.

For example, on any given connection_binding row in the database, the connect_from can be either a company_id or a person_id and the same is true of connect_to. So you say: 'Hey Rails, load up my associated ConnectionBindings' and it gets a row where the connect_from is 11 and the connect_to is 12. But does it do Person.find(12) or Company.find(12)? There is no way to tell!

Instead, you'll have to give Rails some more information:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :connection_bindings
  has_many :person_connections, :through => :connection_bindings, :source => :to_connect, :source_type => 'Person'
  has_many :company_connections, :through => :connection_bindings, :source => :to_connect, :source_type => 'Company

  def connections
    person_connections + company_connections
  end
end
```

You'll need to build that on the other side (as well as the associated :from_connect's) but it depends on how you're using these connections. Should be enough to get you started.

It is a lot more typing than you're used to in the magical world of Ruby and Rails, but it is a very complex data pattern that you're trying to construct. That doesn't mean it is impossible – Rails, as a good framework, won't stop you from doing anything you really want to – but it is uncommon enough to require some explicitness on your end.

Comment: Thanx for pointing me out. You answer was very helpful. I wrote down the actual solution for me in the next answer.

Comment: I know this is a bit stale, but this was exactly what I needed and the explanation was a huge help. Thanks for typing out the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

A Concern:

```
module Linkable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :links_to, as: :linkable_to, class_name: 'Link' # [this]->[other object]
    has_many :links_from, as: :linkable_from, class_name: 'Link' # [other object]->[this]
  end
end
```

Links Table:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base

  #The idea for this class is to by a double polymorphic table, linking an object to another object
  belongs_to :linkable_from, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :linkable_to, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Comment: This is SO much what I am looking for. Sadly I receive an error message ```ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (TreeLeaf(#47140839607440) expected, got #<TreeNode id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> which is an instance of TreeNode(#70354518897720))```

Comment: TreeLeaf is the double polymorphic join-table

Comment: Should this play a role with polymorphic associations?

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AssociationTypeMismatch.html